# pandas apply only returning first value when using logical indexing

Tags: pandas

I create two dataframes:

```
data = [['John'], ['Mary']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name'])
df1['Height'] = 0

data = [['John', 5], ['Mary', 6]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Height'])

df1

Output:

       Name  Height
    0  John  0
    1  Mary  0

df2

Output:
       Name  Height
    0  John  5
    1  Mary  6
```

Now I try to fill in df1's Height using the values from df2:

```
df1['Height'] = df1.apply(lambda row: df2[df2.Name == row.Name]['Height'], axis = 1)

df1

Output:
       Name  Height
    0  John  5
    1  Mary  Nan
```

Why does only the first name (John) have the Height filled in? Shouldn't apply() be iterating through all the rows of the df1 and returning the Height from df2 where df2 matches the name in the current row of df1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `df2[df2.Name == row.Name]['Height']` returns a series with different indexes. You when Pandas concatenate these series, it yields different columns. In particular:

```
df1.apply(lambda row: df2[df2.Name == row.Name]['Height'], axis = 1)
```

returns:

```
     0    1
0  5.0  NaN
1  NaN  6.0
```

and it looks like Pandas takes the first column to assign when you do:

```
df['Height'] = ...
```

To fix your code, you need to extract the single value:

```
df1['Height'] = df1.apply(lambda row: df2[df2.Name == row.Name]['Height'].iloc[0], axis = 1)
```

However, this is certainly not the best way to approach the problem. You should either take a look at `map` or `merge`. For example:

```
df1['Height'] = df1['Name'].map(df2.set_index('Name')['Height'])
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you for the fast and very helpful response. Yes, it's not the best way for this particular example (merge is better). But I'm working on a different problem where merge isn't appropriate.

Comment: I'll look into whether map will work in my use case. Thanks again, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do a `.merge` which will be more efficient anyway? You can specify just the `Name` column in df1 with `df1[['Name']]` when doing the merge, so you don't create two duplicate `Height` columns.

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1[['Name']], df2,how='left', on='Name')
df1

    Name    Height
0   John    5
1   Mary    6
```

You could also use `.join`:

```
df1 = df1[['Name']].set_index('Name').join(df2.set_index('Name')).reset_index()
```

Comment: merge, and many other techniques would work. For my use case, apply is most efficient.